# Portal 2 Authoring Tools: func_instance_io_proxy not working?

Tags: logic, source-engine

I have a func_instance (which I made myself) of a door in my map. It is supposed to open when a cube is fizzled. I also put a checkmark indicator to make sure I had the cube's logic correct. When the cube is fizzled, the checkmark indicator lights up, but the door does not open. To make sure the door was working, I put a logic_auto into the prefab which opened the door when the map loaded. This worked correctly. I therefore think that there is something wrong with the func_instance_io_proxy, but I do not know what. Here are some screenshots:
[image]

The cube targets the openDoor relay's trigger input via the func_instance_io_proxy. It also targets the checkmark indicator, which properly lights up when the cube is fizzled.

[image]

My door func_instance. The relay on the left opens the door, and the one on the right closes it.

[image]

The logic_auto targets the closeDoor relay on startup, which *does* execute properly, as the door is closed when I go to test the map.

[image]

Finally, the func_instance_io_proxy targets the openDoor's trigger input. However, when I try and access it via the cube, it does not work, and the door does not open.

*By the way, I am running this on linux via wine, which is why it looks like windows 98

**Off-topic question, is this the right place to post this, since it is technically map making, not game development?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was that I had not given my func_instance_io_proxy a name. I will leave this question posted in case anyone else has the same problem.